# I run a composer command and i get error problem with curl

Tags: composer-php, debian

I installed composer and now use this command:

```
composer require php-http/curl-client guzzlehttp/psr7 php-http/message http-interop/http-factory-guzzle
```

I get those errors

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires php-http/curl-client ^2.2 -> satisfiable by php-http/curl-client[2.2.0@.
- php-http/curl-client 2.2.0 requires php-http/httplug ^2.0 -> found php-http/httplug|v2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0] but the package is fixed to v1.1.0 (lock file version) by partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.join and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: Please share more details - according to that error message, `php-http/httplug` is already installed

Comment: I hadn't more details to give, but i retried entering the same cmd and it worked, 0 problem ..... strange
it actually worked in /home/myuser/ ... got vendor stuff installed there but vendor is also in /var/www/html, is it normal?
and the command didn't worked when i was into /var/www/html/